# Is there any way to assign int or strings to a particular value which is not assign as a key in my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

let my dictionary be

```
      dict1={1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four'}
```

If I try to find a value of key which is not in my dictionary like

```
       dict1[5]
```

It will give you an error but is there any way that I do not get an error and get a particular value for every key which is not in my dictionary for e.g 'none' or 'not found'

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1[5]                   # raises  KeyError
dict1.get(5)               # returns None
dict1.get(5, "not found")  # returns "not found"
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Answer (score 0):

> get a particular value for **every key** which is not in my dictionary for e.g 'none' or 'not found'

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

A `defaultdict` will work exactly like a normal `dict`, but it is initialized with a `default_factory` function that takes no arguments and **provides the default value for a nonexistent key**.

`defaultdict` will never throw `KeyError`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda : "notfound")
print(d.keys())
# dict_keys([])
print(d["somekey"])
# notfound
```